# SVN Mirror to become live REPO

Tags: svn

I am creating a SVN replication process and have successfully created the mirrors using svnsync. I have been reading in the redbook and other posts and I'm a bit confused. My question is, if my main server fails with my LIVE SVN Repo, what steps need to be taken to promote the Mirror to the LIVE repo? In this example I'm assuming my mirror is good and up to date.

is it?
 1. modify permissions and users in authz and passwd
 2. change UUID from backup servername to live servername

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should go ahead and make the UUID on the slave (backup) the same as the master (live) now.  There's no point waiting until the master dies to figure you cannot do this.

To promote the slave to master, you'll need to remove the svnsync properties from the revision 0 on the slave repository. Check out the [svnsync Bookkeeping section of this page](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication) in the [Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en) for an idea of what properties need to be removed. You may have to remove hooks scripts protecting the rev props to do this.  This should be your first step.

Your second step would be to modify and synchronize (if need be) the users passwd and authz information.

If you have hook scripts on the master, you'll want to have backups on the slave and have script to get them applied quickly.

If you use an DNS name for you'll then want to point the DNS entry to the slave server instead of the master server. If you not connecting using a DNS entry now, you'll want to start getting everyone moved over sooner than later.  Otherwise the next will be required for all clients who do not use the DNS name for the Subversion server connection.

Note: it may be required for some clients to perform a `svn switch --relocate` command on their working copies.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply!  I will check the bookkeeping section on the svnsync properties in revision 0.  I do have the passwd and authz files on my mirrors now. As far as the hook scripts, thats simply a backup to the mirror and ensure they are in the /hooks folder correct?  I do have a DNS name so I am good there and I'll note the 'svn switch' for our users..

Comment: Thanks I found this useful for the UUID info, however I can't for the life of me see anything on removing properties in the bookkeeping section other that recovering from an error where the repo remains locked for syncing. @user572894 did you end up finding anything on this?

Comment: Scroll down to the pink box labeled "svnsync Bookkeeping".  The summary is that svn 1.6 and later have `svnsync info $repoURL` to show the values in a pretty format, and the actual properties can be shown (in all reasonably recent versions) with `svn proplist --revprop -r0` - so you then know what revision properties to remove.